# ggplot stacked bar chart (proportion) scaled to x variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to create a stacked bar chart of the relative proportion, scaled to the x variable. Here's what I mean.

With a dataframe something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(foo = rep(1:5,500), bar = as.factor(c(rep("a",100), rep("b",100), rep("c",100), rep("d",100), rep("e",100))), baz = c(rep("R", 5*250), rep("CRAN", 5*250)), val = rbinom(5*500,1,0.1))
```

I need to create a plot that combines the following two plots. I need the shape of the second plot and the bar colour coding of the first plot (scaled to the second plot. Ideally I would also plot a density over it (like the first plot).

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(subset(df, val == 1), aes(x = foo)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = bar), position = "fill") + scale_fill_brewer(type = "div", palette = 8, direction = 1) +  facet_wrap(~baz) + geom_density(aes(foo))
ggplot(subset(df, val == 1), aes(x = foo, y = as.factor(foo))) + geom_col(position = "identity") + scale_fill_brewer(type = "div", palette = 8, direction = 1) +  facet_wrap(~baz)
```

The end result should be like the facet on the left (on the image below).
[image: Gimped up geom_bar]

How do I do this in ggplot2?

Comment: Sorry, but I just can't get what the problem is. What do you mean by "scaled to the second plot"? Can't you use the code? Or you want aligned them together?

Comment: @PoGibas, the plot at the end of the question is something I made in GIMP, not an output from R. The left hand facet is what I’m after, the right hand side is the result of the second plot alone. Is that clearer now?

Comment: Please let me know if my solution works for you or even if it's in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that I came up with:

```
df <- data.frame(foo = rep(1:5,500), bar = as.factor(c(rep("a",100), rep    ("b",100), rep("c",100), rep("d",100), rep("e",100))), baz = c(rep("R", 5*250), rep("CRAN", 5*250)), val = rbinom(5*500,1,0.1))

p <- ggplot(subset(df, val == 1), aes(x = foo)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = bar), position = "fill") + scale_fill_brewer(type = "div", palette = 8, direction = 1) +  facet_wrap(~baz)
p1 <- ggplot(subset(df, val == 1), aes(x = foo, y = as.factor(foo))) + geom_col(position = "identity") + scale_fill_brewer(type = "div", palette = 8, direction = 1) +  facet_wrap(~baz)

z <- ggplot_build(p)
z1 <-ggplot_build(p1)
z$data[[1]]$ymin <- z$data[[1]]$ymin*z$data[[1]]$x
z$data[[1]]$ymax <- z$data[[1]]$ymax*z$data[[1]]$x
z$data[[1]]$y <- z$data[[1]]$y*z$data[[1]]$x
z$layout$panel_ranges <- z1$layout$panel_ranges

plot(ggplot_gtable(z))
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Just what I was aiming for]

This works, but I'm open to other (less hacked together) solutions.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
 library(gridExtra)
 grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=1)
```

where `p1` and `p2` are the two ggplots.

```
p1 <- ggplot(subset(df, val == 1), aes(x = foo)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = bar), 
       position = "fill") + scale_fill_brewer(type = "div", palette = 8, 
       direction = 1) +  facet_wrap(~baz) + geom_density(aes(foo))

p2 <- ggplot(subset(df, val == 1), aes(x = foo, y = as.factor(foo))) + 
       geom_col(position = "identity") + scale_fill_brewer(type = "div", 
       palette = 8, direction = 1) +  facet_wrap(~baz)
```

Comment: GridExtra and cow plot are handy for putting plots side by side like this. What I want though is one plot as a meld of these two plots. The shape of p2 (steps from 1 to 5) with the stacked proportions of p1. I'll try and produce an example plot...

Comment: Oh, okay. Please do that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this would work: In `geom_bar()` added `stat = "identity"` and removed `fill = "position"`. And you can replace density with histogram (which is basically the same density).

```
ggplot(subset(df, val == 1), aes(foo)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(y = foo, fill = bar), stat = "identity") + 
    geom_histogram(aes(foo), color = "black") +
    facet_wrap( ~ baz) +
    scale_fill_brewer(type = "div", palette = 8, direction = 1) +
    labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: This won’t do the job unfortunately.

Comment: @Simon How can I improve the plot?

Comment: I came to something similar previously. Do you see how your plot is different from the mock example in the question? So, the first plot gives proportions summing to 1 for each value/category of 'foo' - right. If we take each bar (1:5) in that plot and then multiply it by its value of foo then we would get the stepped plot in the mock example.